# How to make Round Buttons for all screen sizes in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I know how to make perfect circle, logic is to make height and width same and set corner radius to half of width or height. In the code i did the same. and it works on SE or Iphone 5s but when i run it on larger screen devices like iphone 7, i don't get the prefect circle shape. Here is my code --

```
submit.layer.cornerRadius = submit.frame.width/2
```

Here is output from iPhone SE

[image]

Here is output from iPhone 7

[image]

is there any another boolean property which could be used to always keep the button round.

Autolayout constraints
[image]

Comment: How is the size of the button itself set up? If you use Autolayout in Storyboard, please include a screenshot of your Autolayout constraints, if you do it programatically, include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Where is the code that sets the corner radius? What function is it in?

Comment: @DávidPásztor added the screenshot of Autolayout constraints

Comment: @Fogmeister its inside the viewdidLoad function

Comment: @GurtejSingh ok, put it in the viewWillAppear function... or just set it to a constant value. You are setting the height to be 80 and so the width will be 80... so just set the corner radius to 40. (Without the calculation).

Comment: Hmm... are you seeing any error logs about `NSLayoutConstraint` when the view loads? Is it definitely 80x80 when you run the app on all devices?

Comment: Looking to autolayout screenshot attached here, I can see that you have added leading and trailing constraints, this will break out your fix-width constraint on different screen sizes. Remove leading and trailing constraints and use horizontal centre constraint and your button will be of always of 80 unit size.
and use submit.layer.cornerRadius = 40

Note: This will always give you fix size round button irrespective of screen size.

Comment: @Fogmeister yeah i getting bunch of errors actually. like "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000002912b0 UIButton:0x7ff89f72fb30'Submit'.height == 80   (active)>"

Comment: It appears to me that @Fogmeister is correct. You've done everything correct *except* for code placement. `viewDidLoad` does not have the frame size yet... `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is too late in the life cycle (it will get hit more times than needed... `viewWillAppear` should have the frame size and *usually* will get hit only once. For proof, add a print statement and see both the frame size and how many times it prints.

Comment: I can no longer answer but @atrane is correct. You are over constraining your button. You are telling it that it MUST have a width of 80. And you are telling it that it MUST be 120 points from the left and the right edge of the screen. 120 + 120 + 80 = 320. So on a device that is 320 points wide (iPhone SE) it will work. But if you're on a larger device (iPhone 7/7+) then it won't work because 120 + 120 + 80 is not equal to 414. To get around this it will break various constraints to try and make it work. (The errors you are seeing).

Comment: The solution to this is to remove the leading space and trailing space constraints and create a centre horizontally constraint instead. (Look at Anshul's answer below).

Comment: @atrane  Thank you after Remove leading and trailing constraints and use horizontal centre constraint i am getting the perfect rounded button.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks for explaining :) you are awesome :D

Comment: @GurtejSingh you should also accept (and up vote) Anshul's answer below. :)

Comment: After applying 
submit.layer.cornerRadius = submit.frame.width/2

Please add below line like 
submit.layer.clipsToBound = YES;

Please check and if you apply corner radius on viewdidload try on ViewWillAppear

I hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Remove the leading & trailing space from your button constraints & give your button the center of the view through constraints.
To create a perfect round shape(circle) the width and height of the button must be equal for all screen sizes i.e. if the width increases on iphone 7 then the height must also be the same as that of width. So you must set the aspect ratio of the button to 1:1, so that if the screen size changes then the width & height increase in same manner.

Comment: Who gives down vote to this answer ? Can you please explain the reason for down vote ?

Comment: No idea why the down vote is there. This is the only answer that has been give so far that actually solves the problem the OP has.

Comment: I didn't, but nothing in your answer helps - the OP shows a constraint with a 1:1 aspect ratio, code to set the `cornerRadius` to half the width, etc. Good answer not only *explain*, they *correct* and where possible show code.

Comment: @dfd the reason the OP is having the problem is unsatisfiable constraints that are being broken at run time. Moving the code to `viewWillAppear` will make a rounded button but it will be too large as the constraints will have been broken by that time.

Comment: @Fogmeister, I now see that - in the comments. Yes, there is more than one missing piece of critical info in the OP. Hopefully it'll get edited in.

Comment: @dfd yeah, took me a while to spot that that could be the issue :)

Comment: @Fogmeister, thats why I am asking the reason for the downvote. Anyways you write the actual problem is their due to unsatisfied constraints.

Comment: @dfd just solving the constraints issue will also solve the problem.

Comment: I'd stress that in your answer. Just remember, I wasn't the one who down-voted.

Comment: Anshul your solution works !! thanks man !! but you should have explain why i have to Remove the leading & trailing space from my button.  anyway thanks :)

Comment: @GurtejSingh because removing the leading & trailing constraint will result in a button with size 80*80 no matter on which iPhone you are running the app.

Comment: @GurtejSingh giving leading and trailing to a button results in increase in width of the button as the screen size increases.